# Requesting data from my own server?

Tags: android, http, server

I'm not sure how to phrase it but instead of making requests to an api, receiving data on a phone and process that data I wonder if it's possible to make the requests on an external machine and then ask it from the phone for the data I need.

In other words I want a "computer" on which I could make http request, get the results, utlimately process it in java. And only then ask from a phone to that "computer" to get me the processed data I need. What would be that "computer" ? Is it a java server ?

Why I want to do that ? Because the data I will receive will need heavy processing and will be too consuming for my app. I would like to make automated calls on another computer thus the data would be already processed and ready for my app to ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the data from API request only, then you can store the data permanently in your app then you can process with data.

Comment: no that's not what I want to do. I don't want to process the data from my app. I would like to process it elsewhere.